# How to delete/destroy an activerecord results set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a result set like this:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Property ...
```

how delete this activerecord results set from the DB?

Comment: did you get it solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`destroy_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all)/[`delete_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete_all) depending on the needs.